# best way to serialize native C array

Tags: ios

I'm currently using NSCoding to serialize a tree of objects, but 1 of them contains as data member a native C float array with 1,000,000 entries, so in order to serialize it using encodeFloat:forKey: for each array entry, I need to apply 1,000,000 useless keys , that might be very slow. what the prefered way to handle this?

Comment: Well, you could just stuff the bytes into an NSData object, if no pointers are involved.

Answer (score 1):

> for each array entry, I need to apply 1,000,000 useless keys

No, you definitely do not need separate keys for each element. A C array is a contiguous block of memory, so you can simply create a NSData object from that block and store that as Hot Licks suggested. Or, since a million floats will require a fair bit of storage, you might compress the data before storing it. And in fact, you don't really even need NSData -- you can encode a range of bytes directly with `-encodeBytes:length:forKey:`.

Comment: Hi, encodeBytes:length:forKey: accept as parameter (const uint8_t*)and I have (float*), are you sure I can use it?

Comment: Yes, you can use it. You'll need to cast your pointer appropriately, and you'll need to know the size of your array in bytes.